# React: using ? and : to make a decision

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement some functionality to edit some text.

I have a list of objects in state. When I generate the list, I want to check to see if the `update` field is `false` or `true`.

I know that I should probably be using `?` and `:` to make that decision, but unsure how to implement it.

```
function AddPerson(props) {
    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" value= {props.newPerson} onChange = {props.handleUpdate}/>
            <button type="submit" onClick= {props.addNewFriend}> Add New </button>
        </div>
    ) 
}

function Person(props) {
    return (
        props.listOfPeople.map((person, i) => {
            // this doesn't work
            person['update']
            ? null
            : return
            (
                <li key={i} onClick = {(e) => {props.handleEdit(e, person)}}>{person['name']}</li>
            ) 
        })
    )
}
```

What should I modify so that if it returns false, it will return the `<li ..>`?

```
function ListPeople(props) {
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                <Person listOfPeople = {props.people} handleEdit = {props.edit}/>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            newPerson: '',
            people: [{name:'Eric', update: false} , {name:'Rick', update:false}, {name:'Yoni', update:false}]
        };

        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this)
        this.addNewFriend = this.addNewFriend.bind(this)
        this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this)
    }

    handleUpdate(e) {
        this.setState({newPerson: e.target.value})
    }

    addNewFriend(){
        console.log(this.state.newPerson)
        const newFriendList = this.state.people.slice()
        this.setState(
            {
                newPerson: '',
                people: newFriendList.concat({name:this.state.newPerson, update:false})
            }
        )
    }

    handleEdit(e, person) {
        console.log(person)
        return null

    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddPerson handleUpdate = {this.handleUpdate} addNewFriend = {this.addNewFriend} newPerson = {this.state.newPerson} />
                <ListPeople people = {this.state.people} edit={this.handleEdit} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: FYI `cond ? whentrue : whenfalse` is called a [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). I would also avoid using one across multiple lines, as it tends to be hard to read.

Comment: thank you! couldn't find the documentation on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove return and put it before. Do like this

```
props.listOfPeople.map((person, i) => {
  return person['update'] ? null : (
    <li key={i} onClick = {(e) => {props.handleEdit(e, person)}}>{person['name']}</li>
  ) 
})
```

Comment: I have to use return in a map, otherwise nothing shows up

Comment: Thats what i have told. Put return before. Look at the answer again

Comment: This isn't good for checking the length of items. If you are doing something where you want to show a "No Data" based on length, then this would always return a length even though no person has `update` set to true.

Answer (score 1):

When using `.map` a value HAS to be returned. If you return nothing then you get a null value in the array. Instead, you should first `filter` your array and then run the `map`:

```
function Person(props) {
    return (
        props.listOfPeople.filter( person => person.update ).map( (person, i) => {
            return <li key={i} onClick = {(e) => {props.handleEdit(e, person)}}>{person['name']}</li>
        })
    )
}
```

EDIT:

Render `<li>` or `<input>` based on `person.update`:

```
function Person(props) {
    return (
        props.listOfPeople.map( (person, i) => {
            if(person.update) {
                return <li key={i}><input /></li>
            }else {
                return <li key={i} onClick={ e => props.handleEdit(e, person) }>{person.name}</li>
            }
        })
    )
}
```

EDIT 2:

Foreach loop:

```
function Person(props) {
    let people = [];
    props.listOfPeople.forEach( (person, i) => {
        if(person.update) {
            people.push(<li key={i}><input /></li>);
        }else {
            people.push(<li key={i} onClick={ e => props.handleEdit(e, person) }>{person.name}</li>);
        }
    });
    return people;
}
```

Comment: but what happens to the people when their update is set to true? I want to display them, but in an <input> field so it can be edited.

Comment: @MorganAllen Okay, you didn't post any example code for that. Can you post what you have? You can just do the reverse and return inputs if you want. But if you want it in the same order then your best bet would be to use a `.forEach` and populate an array of "people" components.

Comment: sorry, I'm working on that now :-) but I'm going through you example to understand how it works. Haven't used .filter() before and understanding how it works :-) At the very least, you taught me something new!

Answer (score 0):

One clever trick that I use in React when deciding whether or not to render a component is to take advantage of short circuit evaluation ->

```
props.listOfPeople.map((person, i) =>
  !person['update'] &&
  <li key={i} onClick = {(e) => {props.handleEdit(e, person)}}>{person['name']}</li>
);
```

Comment: Probably should be `&& return ...`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall actually the `return` should be first: `return !person['update'] && ...`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thanks, edited to be put into correct context.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda well, it shouldn’t really matter, should it? Either it’s `undefined` or `false`, React doesn’t care either way (I think?).